# Array multidimensional #calling array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have question about calling array multidimensional. 
I have array like this

```
array(1) { ["month"]=> array(2) { 
["January"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(4) "2100" } [1]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(2) "50" } [2]=> array(1) { [3]=> string(4) "7858" } [3]=> array(1) { [4]=> string(4) "3535" } } 
["December"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(3) "123" } [1]=> array(1) { [2]=> string(4) "1900" } } } }
```

if I convert to json_encode, like this:

```
string(111) "{"month":{"January":[{"1":"2100"},{"2":"50"},{"3":"7858"},{"4":"3535"}],"December":[{"1":"123"},{"2":"1900"}]}}"
```

"month" have 2 element right? (January and December) 
and January have 4 element;

question is: How to call array month with value January and December without child value in January and December? 
I think like this: `array (2) => {[January][December]}`

Comment: array_keys($array);

Comment: thanks Nan it's works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
array_keys($array['month']);
```

it will solves your problem https://eval.in/938638`

Comment: thanks guys :) you solved it

Answer (score 0):

Specific to your question use :
`array_keys($array['month']);`

Comment: thanks Prathamesh palav :) solved it